# what is the right way to use having in a participle clause? Is "I went out having eaten lunch" okay?

Tags: grammar, word-order, gerund-clauses

> Having eaten lunch, I went out.

Is it correct and grammatical to say

> I went out having eaten lunch.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that '*having eaten lunch*' is, here, a descriptive gerund phrase. As such, it can appear in either position, though some people might find it easier to read with an added comma, especially if it were part of a longer sentence:

> I went out, having eaten lunch, and street-food sellers immediately assailed me with their cries.